# a two or three-pane hierarchical list app with several scrollable areas - what language handles that well?

Tags: php, javascript, ruby-on-rails, django

*My question is in bold (see below) but I hope to provide some insight into my issues just in case it helps anyone who could answer my question.*

I'm not sure which framework or language is the best for this job but I'd like to make an app that has two or three independently scrollable areas, similar to a 2 column template, that are all dynamically updated. Users can populate each list separately as they go and yah know ... I really don't want the app to move slowly in any way. It needs to be jerky with almost knee-jerk reactions to input.

I've read some interesting things about speeds for each language that I'm considering (php and python - possibly java or ruby) and well, I can't really decide for myself since I don't yet know what's going on to create any slowdowns.

The app would be very simple requiring basic information on a user and letting the user basically grow their own database of lists themselves. Some fancy things would happen on the site per the users input or list updates like color changes or pictures and numbers that change .. maybe a graph or something.

All that said, I hope my question(s) is simple and answerable:

**What is a useful programming language and/or framework for making and handling user created hierarchical lists that would ultimately grow in complexity? And how does the language differ from the others for tasks like ones as described in this post?**

Just trying to find the right/best/effective tool for this particular job.

*By the way, I'm new to programming but have covered the basic tutorials for python (plus some django) and php via youtube mostly - I've got a few books in the queue. be gentle*

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you will conclusively be able to decide on a language for your task based on clear evidence of it outperforming others for similar task.

There's too many variables to factor in.

My take is, a well built app, whatever the technology would perform as well as the other one with different technologies, but built well. The difference wouldn't be much to make a fuss over.

Some things that are of note:

- The client side code, HTML, CSS and Javascript would need to be top notch. You need to
- Combine that with a good host, a nicely constructed and tuned database, a good lean method of communication back and forth between client and server.
- Use gzip, caching, minifying and combining scripts, stylesheets, make fewer http requestes,
- Architect the application with performance in mind from the get go.

Comment: Awesome answer! I didn't consider that perspective. From your response I've gathered that I should design around performance by - well what stood out was "make fewer http requests". That makes sense. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

If you are new to programming then the language/framework will be the least of your problems. You tried a little Python and some PHP. Which language did you find easier to grasp? Whichever one that was, pick it and just start writing.

As you work on your project and become a better programmer you can revisit the language/framework debate (although, to be honest, the programmer influences the site performance more than the framework).

Comment: Python was the easier language to grasp, however, as of right now I've found very very good php tutorials that walk through the ins and outs of making a webapp. I haven't found any such tutorial for python. So in order to get this show on the road, I think I'll dig into the language which I could find the most complete picture of, from the basics and advanced topics to interacting with the other languages that control other aspects of the app - php.